# Show count of all google map markers

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-markers

Is there any easy way using the api to get a count of all markers on a map?
I have a page similar to this http://www.gorissen.info/Pierre/maps/googleMapLocationv3.php where a user can add markers by clicking on the map. I'd also like to show a count of all the markers. I could do this by declaring a global count var and incrementing it in the event listener, but I thought it would be better if there was an API method I could use and I can find it in the docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I was looking for was getMarkerCount function of [MarkerManager](https://github.com/googlemaps/v3-utility-library/tree/master/markermanager).

[Documentation](http://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/googlemaps/v3-utility-library/blob/master/markermanager/docs/reference.html)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of MarkerManager you can use [MarkerCluster](https://github.com/googlemaps/js-marker-clusterer) class, the class creates and manages per-zoom-level clusters for large amounts of markers.

[Documentation](https://googlemaps.github.io/js-marker-clusterer/docs/reference.html)